# jQuery Mobile data-native-menu="true" New Window issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, coldfusion

I added some new choices to my Select Menu and now JQM changed the "pop-up" behavior to a new window with a black background along with the menu choices?

I'm OK with the new window, but now my custom JavaScript code is no longer triggered because of the new JQM pop-up window?

Here's my Select Menu code:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="ttType">Work-Order Type:<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select name="ttType" id="ttType" data-native-menu="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="d">
        <cfoutput query="rsType" group="ttOption">
            <optgroup label="#ttOption#">
            <cfoutput>
                <option value="#ttDesc#">#ttDesc#</option>
            </cfoutput>
            </optgroup>
        </cfoutput>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here's the field that no longer works:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="ttEscalate">Escalation:<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input name="ttEscalate" type="text" id="ttEscalate" value="" readonly="readonly" 
        wdg:subtype="N1DependentField" data-mini="true" wdg:type="widget"
        wdg:recordset="rsType" wdg:valuefield="ttDefEsc" wdg:pkey="ttDesc"
        wdg:triggerobject="ttType"/>
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
```

Basically, when the "Select Type" value changes, I automatically fill in the Escalation text field with a "related value"

How do I stop JQM from defaulting to that black window? I'd prefer to just have the select drop-down stay on the same page.

PS: If I change the `data-native-menu` back to `false`, everything works fine, but I lose all the nice JQM formatting!

Comment: when the option list would be higher than the screen size, JQM is creating a new page which will hold that long option list, to avoid some typical issues related to have two nested scrollable elements, and so on. The second example here is showing a long list: [JQM Custom select menu](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/)

Comment: I've tried this using that example (& jqm v1.45) but it doesn't wotk in my case either?

Comment: i believe the black background is due to your  `data-theme="d"` - try to use theme "a"